# Support for ARM processors and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: software-installation, hardware

A while ago I found a site that stated that elementary OS supports ARM processors, however I have not been able to confirm this.

The OS is a very nice experience and would go well on my **Samsung Tab S 10.5**:

- Is ARM support native?
- If not, are there plans for ARM support?
- If not, is there a way to make elementary OS work on ARMv7 processors?

Comment: For elementary to work well on (most) tablets you should also consider touch support of the system. Currently the UI seems pretty much focused on point&click input, though I have not tested it on any touch device myself. Maybe it works well there, maybe not...

Comment: I would love to have elementary OS on my Nexus 9 tablet

Comment: Maybe you could try building Pantheon and all the elementary OS software for ARM (64) and installing it on your device. I have found a way to run Ubuntu on the Nexus 9 (http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-9/general/guide-linux-nexus-9-t2985958) and other Nexus devices like the Nexus 10 and 7 (Google it). I do not know about your Samsung tablet since Samsung devices are locked down unlike Nexus

Comment: is the Image Safe or maybe an Hack and unsure for work

Answer (score 12):

There are currently no ARM images you can download from elementary. However, we do build armhf packages in our [stable](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable) and [os-patches](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/os-patches) repositories. This means you could theoretically attempt installing an ARM compatible version of Ubuntu, add our repositories, and install the Pantheon desktop.

ARM images are something we're interested in provided in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial build of Elementary OS for the Raspberry Pi 4 here: https://github.com/meisenzahl/elementary-os-unofficial/tree/master/hera/arm64/raspi4

Comment: Now with the new Apple Silicon Macs (*M1*), when Ubuntu starts working on these, it would be so neat to run Elementary on them instead...

Answer (score 0):

Since December 2020, early access builds have been available to financial supporters of Elementary:

> https://blog.elementary.io/elementary-os-on-raspberry-pi/

When support does land, it will require Elementary 6:

> https://github.com/elementary/os/wiki/Raspberry-Pi

It is unclear if support will land alongside the soon to be released Elementary 6, or will come later as a specific edition.

These issues will be the ones to keep your eyes on:

https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/472