# What computer architectures are compatible?

Tags: system-installation

What computer architectures are available for elementary OS? Also where can I find (official) list of which architectures are available for elementary OS? For example, see [Ubuntu's](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Architectures).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently [2 versions](http://elementary.io/docs/installation) of elementary OS available:

> elementary OS is currently built for two processor architectures, 32-bit and 64-bit

These architectures are formally known as `i386` and `amd64`, respectively

Comment: Well, I believe, I know this. Can you mention about remaining as I linked in Ubuntu post.

Comment: There is no 'remaining'. eOS is available for 2 architectures, only. Ubuntu is available on many more

Comment: Well, please edit and mention __only__ `available for these two at the moment` @emjaySX

Comment: Someone gotta/gonna make an i386 Loki ISO.

Answer (score 2):

- With the 2016 Loki release, **only 64-bit (`amd64`) processors are supported**.
- Earlier releases had [supported 32-bit (`i386`) processors](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8266/5565).
- [ARM processors are currently unsupported.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1437/5565)
- For more on elementary OS's current compatibility and system requirements, see the links [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8266/5565).